# Databricks autoloader duplicated column name

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-autoloader

I want to stream data from MS Defender lake houseusing autoloader. Data have this folder structure in Blob storage: y=2023/m=06/d=27/h=23/m=00
[image]

Problem is that into streaming are included even partition columns and there is column named "m" twice. Once for month and once for minute. I tried to explicitly select columns for stream read but this is not working.
Any idea how to either omit partition columns or drop them before I get error?

My code:

```
bronze_df = (spark.readStream
  .format("cloudFiles")
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")
  .option("badRecordsPath", bad_record_path)
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", checkpoint_path)
  .load(f"{defender_adls}")
  .selectExpr("Tenant", "category", "operationName", "properties", "tenantId", "time")
  )
```

error message: [STREAM_FAILED] Query [id = f87a50cb-97f4-450f-a59c-b296109a21aa, runId = 68b2056e-767c-4df0-9935-c55f39d7c0e0] terminated with exception: [AMBIGUOUS_REFERENCE] Reference `m` is ambiguous, could be: [`m`, `m`].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the approach to Filter to drop a specific partition.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df = spark.readStream.format('cloudFiles') \
        .option('cloudFiles.format', 'CSV') \
        .option('cloudFiles.schemaLocation', schema_loc) \
        .option('header', True) \
        .load(source_data_loc)
df_filtered = df.filter((col('y') != '2023') & 
                        (col('m') != '06') & 
                        (col('d') != '27') & 
                        (col('h') != '23') & 
                        (col('m') != '00'))
df_filtered.show()
```

[image]

I have used CSV file as an example.

**ADLS File Path:**
[image]

You can try the below approach

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
source_data_loc = "abfss://folder02@dileepstoragegen2.dfs.core.windows.net/actual_data_csv/y=2023/m=06/d=27/h=23/m=00"
target_data_loc = "abfss://folder02@dileepstoragegen2.dfs.core.windows.net/Autoloader/output.csv"
checkpoint_data_loc = "abfss://folder02@dileepstoragegen2.dfs.core.windows.net/checkpoints"
schema_loc = "abfss://folder02@dileepstoragegen2.dfs.core.windows.net/schema"
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("AzureStorageExample").getOrCreate()
customSchema = StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("age", IntegerType(), True)
])
df = spark.readStream.format('cloudFiles') \
    .option('cloudFiles.format', "CSV") \
    .option('cloudFiles.schemaLocation', schema_loc) \
    .option('header', True) \
    .schema(customSchema) \
    .load(source_data_loc)
df = df.drop('year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute')
df.display()
```

[image]

[image]

- In the above code defines a custom schema using **StructType** and **StructField** to specify the structure of the data.
- And drops specific columns from the DataFrame, including '**year**','**month**', '**day**', '**hour**', and '**minute**'.

Comment: Exactly, I needed to create schema and set it as option in the stream: 

json_schema = StructType([
StructField('properties', StructType([
             StructField('AlertId', StringType(), True)
             ]))...


bronze_df = (spark.readStream
      .format("cloudFiles")
      .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")
      .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", checkpoint_path)
      .option('cloudFiles.useIncrementalListing', 'true')
      .schema(json_schema)
 ...